# Data loss from duplicate vg name?

Tags: lvm

I have a desktop and a laptop, both running Debian 9.

I had an issue with my laptop which required removing the hard drive and mounting on my desktop to back up some files before doing a full reinstall.

When I mounted the laptop hard drive, I got some warnings from the various vg commands about a duplicate vg name. Turns out the laptop (despite naming the system something different) had the exact same vg name as my desktop hard drive!

I immediately renamed the vg of the laptop hard drive to something else.

However...is it possible that during the 15 or so minutes that it took me to figure out what was going on, that my desktop hard drive had any data loss due to this duplicate vg issue?

Comment: No data loss. LVM noticed the duplicate volume group name and stubbornly refused to do anything with it until the issue was corrected.

Comment: Thank you for your help!